# Store data in mysql from specific card in recyclerview with button using volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I am working on app that fetches data using volley and displays in feed using recyclerview.i have a button in each card that when clicked, will count the number of clicks and display it in a textview in that particular card(like instagram like button). Now i want the value of clicks to also be stored in a column(likes) on the same row as the other items in the card in my mysql database when the button is clicked. This is what i tried doing but i'm not getting it.Can anyone please help? THis is my code...

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.myfeed;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder holder,    final int position) {
        //Getting the particular item from the list
          final SuperHero superHero = superHeroes.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());
        holder.textViewLikes.setText(superHero.getLikes());



        holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count;


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count = 0;

                superHeroes.get(position).setCount(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + 1);
                holder.txtCount.setText(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + "");


                final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/likes.php";
                final String KEY_LIKES = "likes";
                final String likes = holder.txtCount.setText(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + "".toString().trim();


                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        params.put(KEY_LIKES,likes);


                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }



        });



    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public TextView textViewLikes;
        public TextView txtCount;
        public ImageButton custom_button;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlikes);
            txtCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            custom_button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send that particular card (data) id to server b'z in multi user case it may happen many user likes the same so ?

on the other hand at server side when you get request get count from db and add one into it and send that respond to your device and also store it into db and when you get response display like count to user.